# Case in list - Tableau

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dashboard, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to filter out a huge amount of data out so i decided to create a calculated field and using case if product_id in the list then '1' else '0'
but for some reason it though syntax error.

this is my calculated field:

CASE when product_id in (
'31049','31048','26166','27816','26031','28861','28864','28863','28203','28110','20641','38112','45174','20645','28404','20646','20648','26159','33287','31417','40551','41020','40550','40550','40553','40554','29804','29941','31430','33354','36730','26073','31432','31433','31431','38154','38166','26029','28341','45138','38069','42069','26060','26060','33886','33886','28392','29518','44879','20651','20655','42914','37535','28031','27588','29297','37688','37709','29551','29551','30183','29550','26187','29549','41348') THEN '1' ELSE '0'
END

Any idea who it should be written?

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_logical.htm

Comment: The syntax for the CASE statement in Tableau’s calculation language is slightly different than the syntax in SQL. Tableau’s calculation language is not SQL but it does eventually cause SQL to be produced. The syntax is described in the documentation link in the previous comment

Comment: You could also replace the two words "CASE when" with the word "IF"

Answer (score 2):

On a sample dataset this works:

```
SELECT RIDE_ID as ri,
CASE 
 WHEN ri in ('5EB0FAD625CFAEAB', '5A9314E3AF8DCC30') THEN '1'
 ELSE '0'
END AS result
FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS LIMIT 10;
```

I get:
[image]

Comment: yes it works in the database but not in Tableau :) I couldn't run it in a calculated field

Comment: So the error is then on Tableau and not Snowflake? I am not familiar with how calculated fields work in Tableau unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> *yes it works in the database but not in Tableau :) I couldn't run it in a calculated field*

Maybe using `LATERAL` would allow to run it from Tableau:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(ID  INT, product_id TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, '31049'),(2,'31048'), (3, '100');


SELECT *
FROM t
,LATERAL (SELECT CASE WHEN t.product_id IN ( '31049','31048','26166','27816'/*...*/) 
                      THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS s(result);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option— create a table with your keys that you wish to filter, and then use a join to let the database do the work. Could be easier to maintain. Likely more efficient

Another option is to create a set in Tableau based on the product_id field. Define that set by checking the product ids you wish, and then place the set of the filter shelf to filter to either include or exclude the product_ids in your set.